# HTML content is not being cleared by innerHTML, just added to the bottom of previous loaded content

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

For a university project, I'm displaying jobs in Leeds using mainly JavaScript and JSON. The idea is that the JSON part-time file is shown on page load, then a user can select a different job category and then it loads the new JSON file and replaces the HTML.

I believe my code is almost there, I've attempted to figure out how to call a function again as my previous code had lots of repetition. However, instead of replacing the `innerHTML` when an option is selected, it just adds the new content to the bottom of the previous option's HTML. I can't figure out why this is?

I've attempted to clear the ID before the function starts again but this doesn't work. Perhaps I'm not calling my functions correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
window.onload = function() {
    var jobURL = "";

    //Run function
    loadJobs();

    //If dropdown is changed
    function change(){
        var jobType = document.getElementById("jobtype");
        var selectedValue = jobType.options[jobType.selectedIndex].value;

        if (selectedValue == "part") {
            var jobURL = "https://example.com/reed_parttime.php";
        }
        if (selectedValue == "temp") {
            var jobURL = "https://example.com/reed_temp.php";
        }
        if (selectedValue == "graduate") {
            var jobURL = "https://example.com/reed_graduate.php";
        }
        return jobURL;
    }
    document.getElementById("jobtype").onchange = change;

    //Show jobs function
    function loadJobs() {  
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";

        var URL = change();

        $.getJSON(URL, function(data) {            
            data.results.forEach(function(jobinfo) {
                HTMLTemplate += `
                    <div class="row">
                        <a href="${jobinfo.jobUrl}" target="_blank">
                            <p>${jobinfo.jobTitle}</p>
                            <p>${jobinfo.employerName}</p>
                            <p>${jobinfo.jobDescription}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                `;
            });
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = HTMLTemplate;
        });
    }

    //Repeat function again when button is clicked
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", loadJobs);

}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the getJSON callback (use the dev tools or add a line `debugger;` inside the function). That way you can inspect the content of the div. Maybe the content is getting replaced but `data.results` has more data than you think.

Comment: you clear the element but you forgot to clear your template variable (`HTMLTemplate`), which looks to be global or in a higher scope so it retains your previous html. Either make it a local variable or clear it at the same time you clear the element

Comment: @PatrickEvans Doh! That was it, thanks so much for you help!